# python code works but not in p2exe executable

Tags: python, path, executable, py2exe

The following code works on its own. I have created an executable with py2exe which isn't working. The script processes and sorts some csv files. If I put this code in the "dist" directory where the executable is run (so it has the same filepath depth from the csv files being processed), the code works; but the executable itself in that same directory doesn't work.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

directory = os.path.sep.join(current_dir.split(os.path.sep)[:-2])
csvfiles = os.path.join(directory, '*.csv')
for csvfile in glob.glob(csvfiles):
    filename = os.path.basename(csvfile)
    if '_sorted' in filename:
        print "Remove this file"
        os.remove(csvfile)

csvfiles = os.path.join(directory, '*.csv')
for csvfile in glob.glob(csvfiles):
    filename = csvfile
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    df = df[df["ORGANIZATION"]!="WPPL"]
    df = df.sort('MEETING START TIME')    
    #write new csv file
    df.to_csv(filename + '_sorted.csv', cols=["DATE","MEETING START TIME","MEETING END TIME","DESCRIPTION","ORGANIZATION","LOCATION"],index=False)

raw_input("Press enter to close")
```

Also the raw input statement isn't keeping the screen open so I can't really see what's going on.

thanks

Comment: You really shouldn't be trying to access things off `__file__` in a `py2exe` executable. Is there a reason you're not using [`data_files`](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files) or, better, `setuptools` and its `pkgresources`, instead?

Comment: As a side note, calling `str.split` on a pathname is a bad idea. You're already using `os.path` for all of your other path manipulations; what's wrong with calling `dirname(dirname(current_dir))` or similar?

Comment: the reason I'm not using the things you suggest is I'm a python n00b.  :-)
I was finding things in other threads that `_file_`might be the problem. I would use data_files for the py2exe setup script, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to access data files as relative paths off `dirname(__file__)` is a really bad idea, unless you only want to run the program in the build tree. If you want to be able to install and run the program—whether using py2exe or any other mechanism—you're just asking for trouble.

If you're trying to package files with the executable, the right way to do this is with either the [`data_files`](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files) mechanism from `py2exe`, or, if you can install and use `setuptools`, the more powerful and flexible [Package Resources](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs#accessing-package-resources) mechanism.

If, on the other hand, you want the user to supply the CSV files after installing your app, you almost certainly don't want to make him put them into your app's directory. The usual thing to do is access them as relative paths off the current working directory. In other words, just use `.`, not `dirname(__file__)`.

But, if you really want to do this… the problem is that `__file__` is the filename of your main script—which of course isn't useful when you're running a bundled executable. You can use `sys.argv[0]` or `sys.executable`, depending on your use case.

Comment: I want to setup a directory where the files will be deposited. Based on how I have the script setup now, the executable is in a subdirectory within that directory. I would like executable to be portable, so that if the main directory is moved, the relationship between the csv files and the executable is maintained no matter where it is placed.

Comment: OK, if the end user is depositing the files, `data_files` is the wrong answer. Making users put files into you're app's directory is almost always a bad design, but if that's what you want, the last paragraph if your answer. (Why not let them pass the files, or a directory full of files, as a command-line arg, or drag&drop them to your exe, instead of copying them to your directory and then running the app? Without knowing how it's used, I can't be sure that's a better design, but it's the way _most_ apps work, and that's not for no reason.)

Comment: the person will be downloading the files from a web-based interface and saving each csv file into a preset directory. I am hoping to run the script as a scheduled task, or at the very least have the employee double-click on a desktop shortcut. In short, I am trying to automate a process for someone who isn't terribly skilled, technologically. I want to have the files in `projectfolder` which will also contain a subdirectory for the app -- `projectfolder/appdirectory` the files won't go in the app directory itself

Comment: Thanks, @abarnert. `sys,argv[0]` did it.